# Upload XmlDocument to endpoint

Tags: c#, xml, post, dotnet-httpclient, xmldocument

im trying to upload an XmlDocument to an endpoint but i must be doing something wrong because it returns "Bad Request", here is what i have tried:

the endpoing we are talking about is this one (Validar Semilla):
[link to the swagger](https://ecf.dgii.gov.do/TesteCF/Autenticacion/help/index.html) 
if i manually  upload the file in the swagger test it works, so my xml is in good shape.

snippet 1:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var someXmlString = MyXMLDoc.InnerXml;
var stringContent = new StringContent(someXmlString, Encoding.UTF8, "multipart/form-data");
var respone = await httpClient.PutAsync("/someurl", stringContent);
```

snippet 2:

```
public static string postXMLData(string destinationUrl, string requestXml)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; encoding='utf-8'";
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.Method = "POST";
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                return responseStr;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Sample XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SemillaModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <valor>lWVzKj0dStSuFkR3nXx2mrf2R2q9J+x6JVuPk8jmx0Bwr8DUmI1A9+eld/lot8MNNhC17k8fLeQLGKXW2naiLXXJ41rf0GNS6vlz0CGvuMaCDKElzpnR4NNBBo6XRNcoCEEaA+3H0kBItG1W+bU0pA==</valor>
  <fecha>2021-07-10T10:46:28.4448582-04:00</fecha>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <DigestValue>VBFrBAoKPWRlOQO6RgVkY/3Jh6nNERnG2uGK+thFd24=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>ValuesIDoNotFeelSafeSharing</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>ValuesIDoNotFeelSafeSharing</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</SemillaModel>
```

I'm new to XML, what am i doing wrong? any article that could help me?

Comment: Any reason why you use (multipart/form-data")? , this need if you post a file and endpoint is expecting a file. In your case the api is expecting a xml string it seems. So try to put application/xml.

Comment: @DarshaniJayasekara  when testing the endpoint in swagger that's what is shown there

Comment: If the api is expecting a file content you should pass a file content not string content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass file content, not string content. Try something like below.

```
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())  
{  
    byte[] Bytes = new byte[xmlfile.InputStream.Length + 1];  
    file.InputStream.Read(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);  
    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(Bytes);  
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition =
    new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = file.FileName };  

   content.Add(fileContent); 

   var requestUri = "http://{api url} ";  
   var result = client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;  
                
}
```

Comment: a friend sent me a snippet similar to this, but is the same approach , thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to validate xml structure, you can do it online: https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator